# Page height and width of a PDF

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf

I want to get the page height and width of a PDF in my app. How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can get it this way,

```
float width = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pdfPageRef, kCGPDFMediaBox).size.width;
float height = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pdfPageRef, kCGPDFMediaBox).size.height;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me from where i can get this 2 variable values pdfPageRef and kCGPDFMediaBox

Comment: kCGPDFMediaBox is not a variable, pdfPageref is the PDF page reference.

Comment: How can I get the PDF page reference if I start with a `PDFDocument *` object?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `PDFDocument document` you can get the page:

```
PDFPage *page = [document pageAtIndex:pageIndex];
```

Based on Vignesh's answer you can then do the following with the page:

```
CGFloat pageWidth = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page.pageRef, kCGPDFMediaBox).size.width;
CGFloat pageHeight = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page.pageRef, kCGPDFMediaBox).size.height;
```